# palindrome number

Tags: palindrome

How to find the $n$-th term of the series.

1

11

101

1001

10001

100001

1000001

Comment: $10001$ is a palindrome as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The smallest $n$-digit palindrome is $$10^{n-1}+1: n>1$$

Comment: except when n=1 of course!

Comment: @DCarter Yes, then it is $1$ (or $0$) and not $2$

Comment: I am not able to upvote.Pease help.

Comment: Also not true when n=0 for those who like the initial term to be $P_0$. I've edited the answer to make it technically correct.

Comment: @MartinHansen A $0$-digit number makes no sense to my opinion. But the restriction to $n>1$ is a useful edit.

Comment: @Peter, Yes I agree !